# Click on the multiple button to open the dropdown menu in same place

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I am a web developer. Now I am developing, my new project but I am having problems. I have created an ebook viewer list. Here are some problems. Some buttons are included such as [Download, Bulk Download, Save to Library and “More”]. Everything is fine but the [more] buttons are not working properly.

I want the list of all my books to be created by clicking on the [more] icon so that the list of [more] buttons can be seen in the right place.

The first list is working properly but I have made a list of other ebook viewers. It is not working properly. Clicking on the [More] button opens the first book list button.

I need help from an expert developer. Here is my project screenshot and source code

[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy1Ng.png)

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @[Sajjad Hosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3969710/sajjad-hosen) This is probably far to late. But because there are other people that want answers to such questions I will put in my two-penny worth. Beginner to beginner.

You have two flaws. The first is that you are using the same `id` (`"myDropdown"`) for all your four menu buttons. Then the browser engine finds the first and that's it. That is why it always opens the first submenu.

The second: it is your function `myFunction` that has a flaw:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

This will always find the same element with `id` (supposedly only one in the DOM). You need to use `this` keyword to refer to the element that was clicked. So your buttons would now look like:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
```

You pass as a paramenter the very element you clicked on.

Now, you have to traverse to your `"myDropdown"` elements because `this` refers to a button and not a menu.

```
function myFunction(el) {
  el.nextSibling.nextSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  console.log(el);
}
```

As you see, your function now uses `el` as parameter. We need to use two `.nextSibling` properties. In your case you divided the `</button>` closing tag and next `<div>` tag with whitespace (new line). This is treated as text which is considered as a new element in DOM. Only the next `.nextSibling` property finally gets your menu element.

Some people advertise such usage of tags: `</button><div>`. Tags are then together.

I am inclined to make as much of this front end code with CSS. So perhaps I could propose my solution. Although there are differences. Here I show only one menu button. And after a click in your solution the submenu remains open. In my solution it is there only as long as a cursor hovers above the Dropdown button and its menu. A warning though for those that will expand a solution for more buttons: you should also change the id's of elements.

If someone finds flaws in my solution I'd be happy to hear from them.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#menubutton {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 0.3125em;
}

#menu {
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.99;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0em;
  top: 5vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.25em;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  transition: height 1s;
  border-radius: 0.3125em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rows {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.25em;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  border-radius: 0.6125em;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menuItem1 {
  bottom: 7.2em;
}

#menuItem2 {
  bottom: 3.6em;
}

#menuItem3 {
  bottom: 0em;
}

#menubutton:hover+#menu,
#menu:hover {
  height: 14.0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div align="center " id="menubutton">Dropdown
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="rows" id="menuItem1">Home</div>
    <div class="rows" id="menuItem2">About</div>
    <div class="rows" id="menuItem3">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a flaw - you can open all four menus at once. You have to control this by Javascript.